# Articles in front of a title

Tags: articles, zero-article

I would like to know if I should omit an article in front of a title.
For example,

> NPR's Michel Martin speaks with **American University professor** Allan Lichtman about the prediction he made two years ago that President Trump will be impeached.  [NPR](http://site:https://www.npr.org/2019/05/12/722647643/professor-s-impeachment-prediction-based-on-deep-study-of-trump-s-character-care)

Here, there is no article.

But,

> Migrant children face bleak conditions at detention facilities along the border. Warren Binford, **a law professor** who visited some of the facilities, speaks to NPR's Lulu Garcia Navarro. [NPR](https://www.npr.org/2019/06/23/735191289/law-professor-describes-poor-conditions-where-migrant-children-are-held)

Here, it has A.

And here again, there is no article:

> NPR's Ari Shapiro speaks with E.J. Dionne of The Washington Post and Eliana Johnson of Politico about **Labor Secretary Alexander** Acosta's resignation, infighting in the Democratic party and the census.[NPR](https://www.npr.org/2019/07/12/741237564/week-in-politics-labor-secretary-acosta-resigns)

How can I know if I need to use a or the in front of a title?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cases with no article, they are using it to introduce someone whose name immediately follows with no comma.  Otherwise there should be an article.

These are correct (but I'm not sure about the capitalization):

NPR's Michael Martin speaks with Allan Lichtman, a professor at American University.

NPR's Michael Martin speaks with professor Allan Lichtman.

Migrant children face bleak conditions at detention facilities along the border, according to law professor Warren Binford.

The labor secretary has resigned.

The Labor Secretary, Alexander Acosta, has resigned.

Labor Secretary Alexander Acosta has resigned.